# How to present UI views for different logged user with array of access rights?

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies

I'm using angular11 and logged in user has data with array [ "seller", "buyer", "manufacturer", "marketer", "content_provider" ..]

Which logged in user might have [ "seller" ] or [ "manufacturer", "marketer"... ] as metadata while logged in.

I'm showing my UI with `*ngIf="this.uiAccess === "seller"`, and  `*ngIf="this.uiAccess !== "buyer"` kinda of way. And that this.uiAccess is stored with website cookies.

How to implement that it supports that there might be more than 1 uiAccess array value for the userinterface and it shows?

This works with only 1 value for the this.uiAccess at the moment and shows views based of that.

Comment: `this.uiAccess.includes('seller')`

Comment: Thank you, this was the most straightforward solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating your own structural directive to handle this:-

https://dev.to/angular/extend-the-ngif-syntax-to-create-a-custom-permission-directive-3ic4

Answer (score 0):

If you create diffrent sites for diffrent roles you could use route guards to prevent navigation onto the sites:

https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3